# Adding unofficial tools to documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation

How do we feel about adding unofficial tools to introductions in documentation?

I recently came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/40485) proposed edit.

The edit suggests an `npm` library to run typescript in the node REPL.

This seems like it might be a useful tool (although I have never heard of this library), but my gut feel is that it doesn't belong on documentation.

How should I proceed? Should the edit be approved or rejected?

Comment: I want to add that, `npm` ecosystem is huge, there is a `npm` package for almost everthing... for even things like generating docs from comments, testing, build tools, bundlers.. etc at least 2 popular libraries/frameworks exists..  now some of the big ones could be documented in their own tags..  but many of the packages have to be used together..  giving examples for them will turn out to be a tutorial of  "How to do X with TUVWYZ" or even "best practices for doing X"

Comment: Reject. There's already information about installing TypeScript via npm in the Install and Setup topic. It's especially not useful in Hello World, because it doesn't even write "Hello World" anywhere ;)